# Need support on new button click to open a URL - pass a document variable value as parameter

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

[image: Upload file spreadsheet data][image: Data record]

I have copied and created the app from the following website.

https://www.bpwebs.com/crud-operations-on-google-sheets-with-online-forms/

Now I want to add a button (which I did) but unable to make it work.

On click on this new button (named "Upload Files"- submit fires.... I want the following to happen when user click this button

-- Should not fire submit
-- should open a new window and open url with a parameter.
-- URL = "https://www.google.com"
-- parameter is the recid - let us assume recid has value 100046
-- dynamically generated URL -- to execute on click of this button would be "https://www.google.com?id=100046"

I am completely new to google sheets and app script. So bear with me for naïve. Please can anyone help me with this. Thanks to the SO community for making people life easier.

Comment: @idfurw  can you help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for:

- [Event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)
- [window.opener.postMessage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)

---

```js
const url = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwyTJsFDgeboCt3jcyKI6KQtZ6svIHPynaStM9AwvzCgCFmbds/exec';
const form = document.forms[0];
form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  window.open(url + '?recid=' + form.recid.value);
});
```

Comment: recid is a form input field. I want to pass this value to a web form to upload pictures related to the record. There is a one to many relationship between record and pictures. So in one sheet save record and in another i upload pictures with recid as the primary key (linkage)

Will try the event.preventDefault and revert,

Comment: Recid is an input field of web form, right? Cannot understand the rationale for 'passing value from web form to another web form in new window with a parameter'.

Comment: We have database operations [add / delete / update] happening in a web app. Now for one database entry ... the user can upload many documents like pictures / pdf etc.
the use will click a href that will open another browser window and allow user to upload the documents. 

When user adds a record - a unique id is generated on insert of a row. 

When user uploads data I need to make sure the recid is passed so I can add that data to the spread sheet record file. Basically it is the link key [Primary key / Foriegn Key] Master child link

Comment: [e.parameter](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#request_parameters)

Comment: https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwyTJsFDgeboCt3jcyKI6KQtZ6svIHPynaStM9AwvzCgCFmbds/exec

try adding a record. the record will be shown in right side data table post addition

Click on upload file to API drive .... this uploads the file to google drive and creates a record in spreadsheet. 

Appreciate your time and help.

Comment: User first creates a record and saves [post event fires and saves record].

Then they go for upload of multiple files. So e.parameter is out of question.

Comment: The URL doesnt have any parameters from start, what I want to achieve is to programatically add a parameter to the URL in a later function..

Comment: To add it to url you simply need to add the value of recid to the end of the url. Could you please edit your question and be specific and clear what you want to ask.

Comment: To add it to url you simply need to add the value of recid to the end of the url.

pls help me with a example code.

When I try with a static URL it works. but when i try to build the url using onclick it fails.

Comment: Added. Please check.